# Can I safely use two different versions of a service in the same time?

Tags: web-services, xsd, wsdl, versioning

I would be interested if I can use safely two different version of a web-service.
The schema behind the service were updated between versions, but the part that in I use were in practice unchanged (only attributes I never used where removed and I'm not going to use the newly added ones).

After building my application and sending requests to the different versions of the service my application seams to be working fine without any error.

What I'm interested if there is any pitfall that I didn't think of? Does this really work this nicely?

Answer (score 0):

I did it exposing EJB3 as WS. Basically if you only add new methods to your ws and attributes to your objects, old clients can continue to connect to either new and old web-services transparently. 
It is quite risky, because you have to be at least sure you haven't modified existing methods signature or, for example, changed type to object's existing attributes.
Take a look at new generated WSDL and compare it with existing generated by old WS).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It just depends on the way the Web Service versioning was implemented, if both the versions of the service are going against same Datasource, then you may not have much issues.

Usually the trend if there is a newer version of the WSDL if means the service provider will sooner or later push all the clients to newer version, I would always prefer to be on the latest version just to avoid statements like "You are using a older version of Service & we won't fix any issues on the legacy version".

Comment: I generate my classes from WSDL and XSDs and I'm using the latest WSDL. However my application should still work against both versions.